# Software Riddle [Part 5!]

Tags: riddle

> I am a site many use to play games.
>   Others get my game engine to develop them.
>   When developing you use the language Lua.
>   I have many members signed up to use me.

So the question is;

> What the heck am I?

Comment: It's bad form to have hidden information that's central to the puzzle.

Comment: @xnor I don't have any?

Comment: I mean your clicking through to your profile. It's a huge hint and was how the puzzles got solved.

Comment: @xnor I didn't want that to happen. Kind of a cheat if you ask me.

Comment: @xnor To be fair, he's had that on his profile for months. He didn't add it to his profile just as a hint for a particular puzzle, as some people have done.

Comment: Is this really a riddle? To me it seems like four plain statements followed by a question; a riddle should surely have some kind of veiled information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the answer

> www.roblox.com

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roblox) or [the site itself](http://www.roblox.com) for why this fits the clues:

> people use it to play and develop games (development "using a sandboxed edition of Lua 5.1"), and many users are signed up to it.

Comment: Cheater! Delete this lol! Or at least give real proof.

Comment: @warspyking - Good enough? :-)

Comment: Yes now ;D lol!

Comment: Is this the right answer?

Comment: @QuyNguyen1013 I was waiting to see if he was gonna rollback the profile stuff. It's good now.

Comment: @warspyking - I was the only person to upvote your question! Maybe it's the sort you only enjoy if you get the answer?

Answer (score 3):

The answer might be

> Steam

I am a site many use to play games.

> Many people play games on the Steam platform.

Others get my game engine to develop them.

> This may be referring to the Leadwerks Game Engine.

When developing you use the language Lua.

> Leadwerks supports Lua as a development language.

I have many members signed up to use me.

> Steam has millions of members.

Comment: Not it... Sorry...